# Setup bitcoind and be able to make a call to GetBlockTemplate

Tags: mining-theory, bitcoin-cli

I have been able to get bitcoind started by giving it the right data directory and configuration file.  I downloaded and ran rpcauth.py from https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/share/rpcauth/rpcauth.py

I am stumped as to what to do next.  I added the rpcauth= line to my bitcoin.conf file.  I have tried various combinations of rpcuser or rpcauth both in the bitcoin.conf file and on the bitcoin-cli command line.

I would like to make bitcoin-cli  getblocktemplate to work so I could better understand what gets returned when one asks for a block to mine.

TIA

Comment: In what way does it not work? What error are you getting?

Comment: The username/password combination is not valid.